# Scaling a CGPath & Class.Type does not have a member named nameHere

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm creating a `UIButton` (drawn from a `CGPath`) that's initialised with a `CGRect` frame, but it won't scale to the size of its view.

Instead I'm trying to scale the path but Xcode doesn't seem too happy with what I'm doing.

```
class MenuButton : UIButton {
    let shortStrokeOrig: CGPath = {
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 2, 2)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 28, 2)

        return path
    }()

    let outlineOrig: CGPath = {
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 10, 27)
        // Blah blah more curves....
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, 13.16,  2.00,  2.00, 13.16,  2, 27)

        return path
    }()

    let shortStroke: CGPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(shortStrokeOrig, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
    let outline: CGPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(outlineOrig, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
}
```

This comes up with the error `MenuButton.Type does not have a member named shortStrokeOrig` and the same for `outlineOrig`.

Not sure why it's complaining. Or if anyone has any better suggestions on how to scale my paths..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `shortStroke` constant initialization -
`CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(shortStrokeOrig, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))`

**Problems**:

- `shortStrokeOrig` -  is declared as instance variable but you use it as a class variable.
- The second argument type of `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath` function is `UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>` not a `CGAffineTransform`.

**Solution**

- Make `shortStrokeOrig` and `outlineOrig` a class variables
- Pass CGAffineTransform as a reference (create a variable and use & when passing it to a function)

**Code:**

```
class MenuButton : UIButton {
    static let shortStrokeOrig: CGPath = {
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 2, 2)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 28, 2)

        return path
        }()

    static let outlineOrig: CGPath = {
        let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 10, 27)
        // Blah blah more curves....
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, 13.16,  2.00,  2.00, 13.16,  2, 27)

        return path
        }()

    static var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5)
    let shortStroke: CGPath! =  CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(MenuButton.shortStrokeOrig, &transform)
    let outline: CGPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(outlineOrig, &transform)
}
```